# Como validar se o cookie foi criado pelo servidor?

Tags: vue.js, kotlin, jax-rs

Resumo:
Tenho um webservice com Quarkus(jax-rs) e Vue.js, Faço uma validação **basic authentication** e então crio um cookie **httpOnly** criptografado...

Quando recebo uma nova solicitação não consigo verificar se este cookie é httpOnly, pois o  retornado não é um `javax.ws.rs.core.NewCookie` e sim um `javax.ws.rs.core.Cookie`

```java
@Provider
open class RequestSecurity : ContainerRequestFilter {
    [...]
    override fun filter(requestContext: ContainerRequestContext?) {
        [...]
        if (requestContext.uriInfo.path != "/login") {
            val cookie = requestContext.cookies[cookieSuffix] // meu problema ta aqui
            if (!cookie.isHttpOnly) {
                requestContext.abortWith(Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED).build())
                return
            }
        } else {
            val cookie = NewCookie(
                    cookieSuffix,
                    encrypt(),
                    "/",
                    null,
                    null,
                    3600,
                    false,
                    true
            )

            requestContext.setProperty("cookieCriptografado", cookie)
        }
    }
}

@Provider
class ResponseSecurity : ContainerResponseFilter {
    override fun filter(requestContext: ContainerRequestContext?, responseContext: ContainerResponseContext?) {
        val cookieProperty = requestContext?.getProperty("cookieCriptografado")
        if (cookieProperty != null && cookieProperty is NewCookie) {
            responseContext?.headers?.add(HttpHeaders.SET_COOKIE, cookieProperty)
        }
    }
}
```

Requisições do lado do vue.js

```js
    doLogin({ commit }, loginData) {
      commit('cleanError');
      commit('loginStart');
      axios({
        url: urlLogin,
        method: 'POST',
        withCredentials: true,
        auth: loginData
      })
        .then(response => {
          const user = response.data;
          commit('loginStop');
          commit('updateUser', user);
          localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
          router.push('/');
        })
        .catch(error => {
          let message;
          if (error.message.includes('401')) {
            message = 'Erro na busca dos dados.';
          }
          commit('loginStop', message);
        });
    },

    doVerifyUser({ commit }, next) {
      commit('verifyUserStart');
      axios({
        url: urlCheck,
        method: 'GET',
        withCredentials: true
      })
        .then(_ => {
          let user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
          if (user) {
            commit('verifyUserStop');
            commit('updateUser', user);
            next();
          } else {
            next('/login');
          }
        })
        .catch(_ => {
          commit('verifyUserStop');
          next('/login');
        });
    }
```

Header do response

```
[Content-Type=application/json,Set-Cookie=QKSESSION="1sCF7zOIQXw3wDoRg90oaQ==";Version=1;Path=/;Max-Age=3600;HttpOnly]
```

Header do request

```
[Accept=application/json, text/plain, */*,Accept-Encoding=gzip, deflate,Accept-Language=pt-BR,pt;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,Connection=keep-alive,Cookie=QKSESSION="1sCF7zOIQXw3wDoRg90oaQ==",Host=10.0.11.68:8080,Origin=http://localhost:8081,Referer=http://localhost:8081/,User-Agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.79 Safari/537.36]
```

Comment: Cookies normais não são armazenados no back-end e sim no front, logo usar `document.cookie` (javascript e vue) já vai saber se armazenou, agora se for sessão (cookie também) vai ter que testar em uma requisição.

Comment: Sim Guilherme, os cookies são armazenados no front-end, porem ao adicionar o httpOnly, o javascript n tem acesso ao cookie...

Comment: Carlos qualquer requisição HTTP futura vai enviar nos headers de req o tal cookie, ai checa com outra requisição do lado do server, não?

Comment: Sim, como coloquei na pergunta (header do request)... esse seria um request qualquer que retorna sim o cookie... porem não me retorna se o cookie é httpOnly.

Comment: Mas é isso que estou falando é pra vc imprimir o cookie do lado do servidor e devolver como um BODY de uma resposta HTTP.